# Pasting values by vlookup in Google Sheets app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I have so far:

Sheet1 contains nearly a hundred columns of data for various individuals, each identified with a Unique ID in column A, which I'm using for lookup functions.

Sheet2 contains a kind of summary template, with each of Sheet1's column fields represented in a single-page view, so that I can select a unique ID and have all the rest of the fields populate the values of that row on Sheet1. Basically wanted to be able to see all of a person's information at roughly the same time.

That's what I have. Here's what I need:

In Sheet2, when I run the lookup script (based on the Unique ID I select), it fills in the blanks with the values from Sheet1 rather than keeping the lookup formula in the cells. What I would like to do is to be able to make changes on Sheet2, as I see fit, then run another button-based script that will update all of Sheet1's values with the information I may have altered from Sheet2.

I'm comfortable with the scripting to copy a cell value to another, but I don't know enough about Google Sheets syntax to know how to do that kind of lookup within scripting. I'm hoping someone can give me a place to start with some code that might be in line with what I'm trying to do.

For example:

Sheet1 says that Dave (ID Person01) has brown eyes, brown hair, and glasses. In Sheet2, I select Person01, click a button, and next to the fields for "Eyes", "Hair" and "Glasses y/n", it populates Brown, Brown, and Yes. But Dave's had corrective surgery since last I updated this, so he no longer has glasses. I change the value on Sheet2 to No in the Glasses y/n field, and click a button at the top of the sheet which updates Sheet1's Person01 row with the relevant information. Sheet1's Dave row now should reflect that Dave does not have glasses.

I'm sure this is doable, I'm just not sure how the syntax lines up. Thank you in advance for any help you're able to give.

Answer (score 0):

Without a sample of you data, it is difficult to tell if this solution meets your requirements. But it should give you some ideas. Sheet1 has the base data. Sheet2 pulls in the data from Sheet1 based on the dropdown (data valadation) in Sheet2!A2. The data from the selection fills in the rest of the row based on two things. First is the formula in Sheet2!A4 which finds the row from Sheet1 of the value selected from the dropdown. Second is the formula in Sheet2!B2 which pulls in the data for the selected value. You cannot change the values in Sheet2 row 2.You will get an array error. Instead make your changes in row three under the current data. When you have made a change or made multiple changes, click the change button and the changes will be made on both Sheet1 and Sheet2 row 2. Sheet2 row 3 will be cleared. See the script editor for the code. Try it. Below is the shared link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16jbRrJZJF5_Jxh062F11tCJQ9XsAq1LuqhzQImG8kRI/edit?usp=sharing

Let me know if you have any questions.